# Replace key column with values using a hash table/dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary, dataframe, merge, hashtable

I would like to merge two dataframes based on mutliple columns. Here based on column B in df1 and all columns from X-Z in df2, but returning values from column X, into V1.
Like a dictionary, if a from df1$B matches with a in df2$X, a is returned to df_merged$V1, but then if c from df1$B matches c with df2$Y, b is returned from df2$X, which is its synonym and etc. Only df2$X can be returned to df_merged$V1

df1

```
A   B
1   a
2   c
3   f
```

and df2

```
X   Y   Z
a   NA  NA
b   c   NA
d   e   f
```

merged_df

```
A   V1
1   a
2   b
3   d
```

Here is my try:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x="B", by.y=c("X", "Y", "Z"), all.x=T)
```

Comment: So you want B in `df1` to match with X in `df2`?

Comment: What's the rule for matching though? how to tell which row in `df1` matches with which row in `df2`?

Comment: Your update does not make sense, how does `df1` come into play here? B does not match with X, so how did you get V1? This is completely different than your original post..

Comment: I get that, but `B` does not match with _any_ column in `df2`, so how to know that `X` is what you want to return as `V1`? Do you mean `B` to be a, b, d instead of a, c, f?

Comment: is it like a dictionary, a from df1$B matches with a in df2$X, returns df_merged$V1, then c from df1$B matches c with df2$Y, but returns b from df2$X , which is its synonym and etc. Only df2$X can be returned to df_merged$V1

Comment: Ah, so Y and Z are keys and X are values? You should put what you have written as a description in your question. This makes it a lot clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this generically with `tidyverse`, or you can actually use a hash/dictionary-like data structure. In R, there is no native hash table class, but you can take advantage of the `hashmap` package, which uses `Rcpp` internally to create hash-like objects:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hashmap)

dict = df2 %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(Value = X) %>%
  gather(Label, Key, -Value) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  {hashmap(.$Key, .$Value)}
```

This gives you a hash table:

```
> dict
## (character) => (character)
##         [e] => [d]        
##         [d] => [d]        
##         [f] => [d]        
##         [b] => [b]        
##         [a] => [a]
```

Now, to extract value using `df1$B` as a key, simply do this:

```
dict[[df1$B]]
# [1] "a" NA  "a" "d"

df1 %>%
  mutate(Value = dict[[B]]) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  select(-B)
```

**Result:**

```
  A Value
1 1     a
3 3     a
4 4     d
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = read.table(text = "A   B
                 1   a
                 2   c
                 3   a
                 4   e", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

df2 = read.table(text = "X   Y   Z
                 a   NA  NA
                 b   NA  NA
                 d   e   f", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Comment: @user2904120 I've posted my original answer as a separate answer, and edited this one to include a solution using a dictionary-like data structure in R. This should work for any number of rows in `df1`, whether there are NA's, duplicates, or mismatches. I've also deleted a bunch of comments to reduce clutter. You should do the same.

Comment: prior to using this solution columns need to be converted to characters, doesn't work with factors

Comment: @user2904120 True, but that can be easily solved by adding `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` to your `dplyr` pipeline. See my updated code and data

Answer (score 1):

Here is the generic version for demonstrative purposes, but this method is less robust, less flexible, and less efficient than using `hashmap`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  mutate(Value = X) %>%
  gather(Label, Key, -Value) %>%
  split(.$Label) %>%
  map_dfr(~ cbind(A = na.omit(match(.$Key, df1$B)), 
              slice(., match(df1$B, .$Key)))) %>%
  select(A, Value) %>%
  arrange(A)
```

**Result:**

```
  A Value
1 1     a
2 3     d
3 4     d
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = read.table(text = "A   B
                 1   a
                 2   c
                 3   f
                 4   e", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 = read.table(text = "X   Y   Z
                 a   NA  NA
                 b   NA  NA
                 d   e   f", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Note:**

I first duplicated `df2$X` because it is technically also a key. I then reshaped `df2` to long form, and `split` by `Key`. For every Key, I `sliced` the rows that match with `df2$B` and `rbind`ing the results together with `map_dfr`. Finally, returning only the `Value` column.

Notice that I used a different `df1` in this example than I did in the `hashmap` example because this method would not work if `df1$B` has duplicates.

Comment: almost perfect, though still getting errors, not sure why: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1400, 1431
In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped

Comment: @user2904120 Any reason you don't like the dictionary answer? `hashmap` is made for this type of problems. This generic solution with `tidyverse` gets the job done for your specific example, but might not be robust enough to work on your real dataset.

Comment: @user2904120 That's why I deleted a bunch of them. You can do the same by clicking on the "x" button at the end of comments. Many of those comments are no longer relevant